# iOS how to implement a tap gesture on a scrollview/webview to "tap out of" a text field?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a text field presented on a side panel over a UIWebView. I'm looking to implement a "tap out of text field" gesture recognizer - if the user taps outside the text field, it will dismiss keyboard and hide the side panel.

I'm using the code below, and it works if the user taps within the side panel, but does not work if the user taps on a UIWebView. **Is there a way to make a Tap Gesture Recognizer work with with a UIWebView - allow interaction with webview, but still do tap out behavior?**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleMenu)];
gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the webview as well with:

`[webView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];`